# Marketing Cloud IP Warmup

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability

I am in the process of planning for a IP Warmup and going through SF documentation to get more insight but I have two questions. I think I know the answer but wanted to conform with the community.

1. I am trying to segment subscribers per the limits of ISP. Let's say I send an email to 5K subscribers in Week1 then in the Week2 increase it to 10K subscribers and so on.  My question here is, The second week's email includes  subscribers from Week1 as well new-subscribers and Week3 includes Week1+Week2+new-subscribers until we hit our desired limits. Is that correct?
2. Since our plan is to have this Warm up over a period of time, I think we have to create diffrent email campaigns not send the same email again and again. Can you please confirm or any suggestions on how we can plan on diffrent content?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same email should not go out to the same recipient, so once you have sent out email 1 to your entire base during first 2-3 weeks, you should start sending another campaign. This will be sent over shorter period, as your daily volume should have increased significantly. Let's say this will go out to everyone in 1-2 weeks. Now you might have a 3rd email, going out to the entire base, over 1-1,5 week, and so on.

So, to answer your questions:

1. You should not send same email to same subscribers more than once. Divide your audience in segments of e.g. 5-10-20.000 and send the email to each of the segments until entire audience is reached. None of your recipients should exist in multiple of these segments. Then you will have your next email, which will start going out to 40-80.000-etc. (e.g. in week 3). Recipients in these segments would also have been in your segments for email 1, this is fine. But again, recipients in your 40k segment should not also be in your 80k segment.
2. My recommendation is to create specific campaigns for warm-up which can be sent out over 2-3 weeks, where the content and offers are not time critical. However it must also drive engagement - as this is a metric confirming to the ISPs that recipients are interested in your sends. So it should not be as generic as branding campaigns with no call to action.

Comment: Thank you @Lucas. Your idea makes sense tome. I was under impression that I have to add up subscribers from previous emails as mentioned in the below thread. It is recommended to use UNION to combine subscribers from previous emails. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335442/email-domain-segments-data-extension-for-ip-warm-up

Comment: @sdondeti the answer you refer to is not really clear, so I can understand your confusion. I can assure you, that you should not send same email to same recipient more than once.